# textview background color is not changing on click in popupwindow

Tags: android

I am using PopUpwindow with textviews in it. Problem is When i click any of the textvies the background color is not changing though it is changing when the textview is focused but not on click.

After clicking i am dismissing the popupwindow , and if i don't dismiss the popupwindow then the background color changes according to the selector :

This is my textview background selector:

```
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focused" />    
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/priornone" /> <!-- default --> </selector>
```

in my popupwindow all i am doing is this :

```
TextView manage_list = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.manage_lists);
manage_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v) 
{

  Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),ManageList.class);
      popupWindow.dismiss();
  startActivity(myIntent);

 }});
```

layout file for popupwindow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/pop_menu_bg"
 android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/manage_lists"
    android:text="Manage lists"
    android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
 >
 </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Its quite strange behaviour everything works well if i don't dismiss the popupwindow but if i dismiss the popupwindow on click textview background doesn't changes.

What am i doing Wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you use the above code, you will be ok:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focused" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/activated" /> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/priornone" />
</selector>
```

You cannot define two different states in an item.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but it didn't helped, still textview background is not changing on click.

Comment: @kay Can you post your layout xml file? I believe this code and the code of the others that answered your question is correct, so the problem may be somewhere else.

Comment: @kay Hm, i don't see anything wrong on your layout xml either. Since you said that this odd behavior occurs when you click the button that dismiss the `PopUpWindow`, maybe the problem is that the `PopUpWindow`'s blocks the UI update of your button. If you really want to change the button's background, set the `activated` drawable dynamically during the `onClick` event with `v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activated)`. Maybe this will trigger the button's update but i am not sure. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

//you need to remove `android:state_pressed="true"` when `android:state_focused="true"` is also true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

[refer here:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

**EDIT:** you need to give your Linearlayout attribute as  `android:clickable="false"`

Comment: that too didn't worked padma. What is happening after i click is this textview background goes transparent & the popupwindow dismisses.

Comment: give it for TextView also as 'android:clickable="true"' and vise versa  .

Answer (score 0):

You will use your TextView like Checkbox,  isn't it?

Use a boolean flag to try this.

```
private boolean clicked = false;

// ...

mytextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        clicked = !clicked;

        if(clicked){
            mytextView.setBackgroundColor(yourcolorclicked);
        }else{
            mytextView.setBackgroundColor(yourcolorunclicked);
        }
        mytextView.invalidate();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a naming conflict. In case none of your changes are showing up, the possibility of it not working because of some kind of a naming issue conflicting with an imported library could be your main problem.